# Is it possible to set persistence unit default catalog at runtime

Tags: jpa, persistence, eclipselink

For the moment I use the table annotation containing the catalog

```
@Table(catalog = "Mycatalog", schema = "MySchema", name = "MyTable")
```

But the catalog name should be made configurable.

The persistence.xml file can not be changed per deployment, and the datasource default database should be set to TempDB. (Another process is locking the catalog quite often and the driver keeps a connection open to the datasource default database) so I am limited to change the default catalog using properties passed to the EntityManagerFactory.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = provider.createEntityManagerFactory(
                "default", properties);
```

Is it possible to set the persistence unit default catalog in the properties?

I am using eclipselink as JPA provider.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use different Catalogs as long as they are in the XML configuration files.

First I removed all @Table annotations from my entity classes and created two orm files.

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="storeone" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm-storeone.xml</mapping-file>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="storetwo" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm-storetwo.xml</mapping-file>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

orm-storeone-xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <entity class="com.package.EntityClass">
        <table catalog="SomeCatalog" schema="SomeSchema" name="SomeTable" />
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

And then in the code where I create my EntityManager I am able to choose between the two catalogs.

```
String persistencUnitName = "storeone";
EntityManagerFactory emf = provider.createEntityManagerFactory(
                persistencUnitName , map);
```

this way I can change between catalogs at runtime, (but I still cannot add new catalogs at runtime).