# Spring Roo @RooJpaActiveRecord parameterized the JPA table catalog

Tags: spring, jpa, parameters, spring-roo, catalog

I need a why to change the JPA catalog element in my java class?  We have many database environments which we need to be able to deploy our application too.  Example: In your dev environment we have a database for new development, and production support.  All database live on the same server so we have the following database names: am_web_dd and am_web_ps.  So we need to be able to change the catalog at build time or start up time.  We've thought of using Maven to do a search and replace during build but I was wondering if there is a way of doing this with a parameter?

Here is one of our @RooJpaActiceRecord statements:

> @RooJpaActiveRecord(catalog = "am_web_t4", schema = "dbo", table = "user_t")

I would like to be able to make catalog a parameter.  Is this possible?  if not what would be the best approach?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I know it is possible from a JPA standpoint, but I don't think you will be able to using straight Roo.  [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431219/is-it-possible-to-set-persistence-unit-default-catalog-at-runtime).

There may also be a way to use a Java Configuration object in Spring to build your JPA Entity Manager.  I think that's were you want to set it.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you suggest of making catalog dynamic would be suitable if you wanted to let the user choose/change the schema on demand, however, it looks like this is not your requirements, so I would steer away from this path as it more difficult than you need.

You can use spring profiles to define different database connections and use an environment variable to define which one is active.  Spring profiles can be set in XML or java configuration classes.